# running bash command within script

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services

i have to run the following command within a script in bash and store its output in a variable. the db_name is another variable that i want to substitute too. Notice the `name-db` and `true`, i don't want my shell to start running them.

> `` aws rds describe-db-snapshots --db-instance-identifier ${db_name} --query 'DBSnapshots[?contains(DBSnapshotIdentifier, `name-db`) == `true`]'.DBSnapshotIdentifier --output text | sort -k8 | tail -n1 | gawk '{print $4}' ``

I started by storing the whole command in a string and then run the string using eval or the string directly but it fails everytime. I guess it keeps expanding the `true` and the `name-db` bit. Any help ?

Comment: can you try `resp=$( aws ..... ); echo $resp` ?  This will actually open a sub-shell and `resp` will contain the output.  Edit: this is kinda the same as the answer from @ruakh.

Comment: Storing commands in strings does not work. See [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). A function, as in ruakh's answer, is the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than storing the command in a string, you're better off storing it in a shell function:

```
function get_latest_foo () {
    local db_name="$1"
    aws rds describe-db-snapshots \
      --db-instance-identifier "$db_name" \
      --query 'DBSnapshots[?contains(DBSnapshotIdentifier, `name-db`) == `true`].DBSnapshotIdentifier' \
      --output text \
    | sort -k8 \
    | tail -n1 \
    | gawk '{print $4}'
}

latest_foo="$(get_latest_foo "$db_name")"
```

(Note: I used `foo` in the function-name because I couldn't tell which field `$4` is. You'll want to change the name to something more meaningful.)